# dissertation formatting. 2" margin on first page of chapter only

Tags: formatting, margins, chapters

I have looked through the questions and have not found an exact answer to solve my concern.

I need the 1st page of each chapter to have a 2" margin at the top, while the rest of the chapter have only 1" margins.

please find code below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb, bm}
\usepackage{dcolumn, multirow}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{subfigure, subfloat, graphicx, float}
\usepackage{anysize, setspace}
\usepackage{verbatim, rotating, paralist}
\usepackage[format=hang]{caption}[2006/03/21]
\usepackage{natbib,url}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\smaller}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\newtheorem{hyp}{Hypothesis}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks = true,
            linkcolor = black,
            urlcolor  = black,
            citecolor = black,
            anchorcolor = black]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\MYhref}[3][blue]{\href{#2}{\color{#1}{#3}}}%
\usepackage{bbding}
\setdefaultenum{I)}{A)}{i.}{a.}
\singlespace
\bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{,}{a}{}{,}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\newcommand{\R}{\textbf{R }}
\pagestyle{plain}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\centerline{TABLE OF CONTENTS}}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\centerline{LIST OF FIGURES}}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\centerline{LIST OF TABLES}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                               {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                               {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                               {\normalfont\scshape\bfseries}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    % The command below sets the bibliography style as American 
       Political Science Review (APSR) style.
\bibliographystyle{apsr}
\singlespace
\thispagestyle{empty}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%  START OF SECTIONS %%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newpage
\doublespacing
\newgeometry{top=2in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in}
   % The command below enters the chapter name into the "table of 
    contents."
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Chapter 1-TITLE. }
\begin{center}
\section*{Chapter 1: \\
 \\
 CHAPTER 1.
\end{center}}
   % The two command below sets the page numbering to Arabic and sets 
  the current page to page 1.
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}
\setcounter{page}{1}
       %The space command sets the space between the text above and the 
       text below.. 
\vspace{2cm}
\doublespacing
\input{Chapter1}
 \lipsum[1-20]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%  Chapter 2       %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\clearpage
\newpage
\doublespacing
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Chapter 2 - Literature.}
\begin{center}
\section*{Chapter 2: \\
 \\
Literature.
 \end{center}}
\vspace{2cm}
\doublespacing
\input{Chapter2}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Is there any reason why you don't use the `report` document class, which has chapters, and would number them automatically?

Comment: `\begin{center}
\section*{Chapter 2: \\
 \\
Literature.
 \end{center}` This should just be `\chapter{Literature}` there should be no formatting in the heading and it should not be in a display environment such as `center`  the formatting of chapters can be specified in the preamble, then also you do not need to change the margins, the specification of `\chapter` can specify the extra vertical space above the heading.

Comment: @Bernard I found a dissertation template from another university and I used that one.  No one in my department uses LaTeX so I just took what seemed to work.  this is the only issue I am having.

Comment: you get _multiple_ errors from the code as posted `! LaTeX Error: Command \bibhang already defined`,  `! LaTeX Error: Command \citename already defined` , `! Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'natbib'.`,  `! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.`

Comment: @davidcarlisle I am not understanding how to do that.  also on the other errors, I have been adding code to the preamble to deal with other concerns.  The code I have actually runs which is my biggest concern right now.  The only formatting issue I have moving forward are my margins which I cannot figure out how to specify as you've stated.

Comment: Assuming the chapter title is the first thing on the page, the effective top margin is the page margin PLUS the spacing down to the chapter title.  Usually these are set separately.  You want 1in - \topmargin-\headheight-\headsep.

Comment: No, if you get an error you should not even _look_ at the pdf output, TeX's recovery from errors is designed to allow further syntax checking of the document but it makes no attempt at making sensible typeset output if you scroll past an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

there are comments inline where I made changes.

```
% I assume you want A4 mot US-letter, and you want chapters so report not article
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

% just for the example
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb, bm}
\usepackage{dcolumn, multirow}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{subfigure, subfloat, graphicx, float}
\usepackage{setspace}
% no\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{verbatim, rotating, paralist}
\usepackage[format=hang]{caption}[2006/03/21]
\usepackage{natbib,url}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
% no if you are using natbib \usepackage{biblatex}
% \AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\smaller}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\newtheorem{hyp}{Hypothesis}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks = true,
            linkcolor = black,
            urlcolor  = black,
            citecolor = black,
            anchorcolor = black]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\MYhref}[3][blue]{\href{#2}{\color{#1}{#3}}}%
\usepackage{bbding}
\setdefaultenum{I)}{A)}{i.}{a.}
\singlespace
\bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{,}{a}{}{,}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\newcommand{\R}{\textbf{R }}
\pagestyle{plain}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}

% I left this but 1in margins on single column A4 makes unreadably long text lines
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}

% No! \ceneterline is not a latex command and \...name nacros should just have text
% to allow language translation, the whole pointof them is that they do not have formatting
% \renewcommand{\contentsname}{\centerline{TABLE OF CONTENTS}}
% \renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\centerline{LIST OF FIGURES}}
% \renewcommand{\listtablename}{\centerline{LIST OF TABLES}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                               {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                               {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                               {\normalfont\scshape\bfseries}}


\renewcommand\@makechapterhead[1]{%
  \vspace*{50pt}% increase this if you need more space above the heading
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \centering % I added centering
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
    % The command below sets the bibliography style as American 
       Political Science Review (APSR) style.
\bibliographystyle{apsr}
\singlespace
\thispagestyle{empty}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%  START OF SECTIONS %%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newpage
\doublespacing
% no \newgeometry{top=2in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in}
%   % The command below enters the chapter name into the "table of 
%    contents."
% \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Chapter 1-TITLE. }
% \begin{center}
% \section*{Chapter 1: \\
 % \\
%  CHAPTER 1.
% \end{center}}
   % The two command below sets the page numbering to Arabic and sets 
%   the current page to page 1.
% enewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}
% \setcounter{page}{1}
       %The space command sets the space between the text above and the 
%        text below.. 
% \vspace{2cm}
\doublespacing


\chapter{TITLE}
%\input{Chapter1}
 \lipsum[1-20]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%  Chapter 2       %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% not needed \chapter does that \clearpage
% \newpage

% done above already \doublespacing
% not needed \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Chapter 2 - Literature.}
% no!! \begin{center}
% \section*{Chapter 2: \\
%  \\
% Literature.
%  \end{center}}
% \vspace{2cm}
% \doublespacing

\chapter{Literature}
%\input{Chapter2}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```